# How can I modify my eclipse.ini settings to build large-scale java projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, memory

I am using IBM WebSphere Integration Developer (WID) which is based on Eclipse. We have a large web system built in this and all the projects are in the stream. It's pretty heavy. Every time I try to build all projects - it takes a really long time and eventually Eclipse runs out of memory.

These are my settings:

```
-startup
plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.101.R34x_v20081125.jar
-install
D:\IBM\WID7
--launcher.library
plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.101.R34x_v20080731
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vm
jdk\jre\bin\j9vm\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Xquickstart
-Xms768m
-Xss4m
-Xmaxf0.1
-Xminf0.05
-Xmx1300m
-Xmnx64m
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-Xscmx96m
-Xshareclasses:name=IBMSDP_%u
-XX:MaxPermSize=448M
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:+AggressiveHeap
-Dorg.eclipse.jdt.core.javamodelcache.ratio=0.0625
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dosgi.bundlefile.limit=100
```

What can I do to actually make Eclipse build all these projects? It does garbage collect but eventually even with GC, it uses everything up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the j9 JVM works like the Oracle JVM, the settings above are setting your maximum heap space to 1300 MB. You can try increasing that amount if your system has enough free RAM to support a larger heap.

The line to edit is `-Xmx1300m`

One more thing to consider: are you certain that your memory errors are because of heap space running out? Keep in mind that the `-Xmx` setting only affects heap space, but a JVM uses memory for other purposes, too.